# options for SQLite DB on windows phone 8

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8

I am  working on SQLite database on windows phone 8. While searchinf for the options to implement the SQLite DB in WP8 Phone I have come across some options.

I want to know, how exactly does one decide on whether to go with sqlite-net available on [GITHUB](https://github.com/peterhuene/sqlite-net-wp8) or a new SQLite wrapper available on [CODEPLEX](http://sqlwinrt.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest) for a windows phone project?

what are the pros and cons of each ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you prefer to work with raw SQL statements or perfer a LINQ to SQL pattern.

Comment: I would like prefer to work with raw SQL statements, but I want to know that is there any performance related issues with the CODEPLEX project ?